# How to make two UIGestures respond simultaneously on two different views?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have View (A) has two subviews: view B and view C. View (B) that has a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and View (C) has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and is hidden by default. When I long press on a View B, view C is shown (`isHidden = false`).

Now, when I long press on view B, view C is shown but gesture defined in it is not responding, gesture defined in view B is still active.

I want to be able to respond to `UIPanGestureRecognizer` of View C when it is shown, and when I release touch I want to ended both gestures a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` of View B, and `UIPanGestureRecognizer` of View C.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does the view C is above on view B? can you provide view's layout?

Comment: Yes, C is above B.

Comment: Can you see the code i embedded?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no necessary to add UIPanGestureRecognizer to View(C), you can recognize finger position in UILongPressGestureRecognizer handle method. look at sample code

declare variables:

```
@IBOutlet var cView: UIView?
```

Here is UILongPressGestureRecognizer handle method:

```
 @IBAction func handleLongPressGesture(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        cView?.isHidden = false
    case .changed:
        if let cView = cView, cView.isHidden == false {
            let location = gesture.location(in: self.cView)
            print("Finger Location - (\(location.x),\(location.y))")
        }
    case .ended, .cancelled:
        cView?.isHidden = true
    default: break
    }
}
```

The code performs your requirements.